# No ideas of this two equals of the Python Array "RELEASE_LEVELS = [ALPHA, BETA, RELEASE_CANDIDATE, FINAL] = ['alpha', 'beta', 'candidate', 'final']"

Tags: python, arrays, odoo

I see

```
RELEASE_LEVELS = [ALPHA, BETA, RELEASE_CANDIDATE, FINAL] = ['alpha', 'beta', 'candidate', 'final']
```

in odoo/conf/release.py of odoo project. I am assuming it's python array. but can't find any detail of it.

What does the two equals mean?

Comment: Do you mean in terms of a general `x = y = z` situation, or more specifically in the `[a,b] = [c,d]` approach? Try this out in the REPL and see what results from that statement. Super easy to test, and educational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short way to write

```
ALPHA, BETA, RELEASE_CANDIDATE, FINAL = 'alpha', 'beta', 'candidate', 'final'
RELEASE_LEVELS = [ALPHA, BETA, RELEASE_CANDIDATE, FINAL]
```

So first it sets the four variables to the corresponding strings, then it sets `RELEASE_LEVELS` to a list (not array) of those four strings.